# Adding a link to gallery image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jQuery gallery script and I would like to add a link to the large image but I am not sure how because the div and image are generated on the fly. 
I really appreciate any advise or suggestions you might have.

Here's what I've tried which works except the first image is broken for some reason.

```
.prepend('<div id="' + id + '"><a class="imghold" href="#"></a></div>')
```

I added the anchor to the div and then this to the img tag:

```
.appendTo('#' + id + ' a.imghold')
```

Which works except the first image in the list is broken. for some reason

Comment: This wall of code is simply too much. You should keep your question simple and clear. Try to provide a [short example](http://sscce.org) of your problem instead, as this will enable us to teach you how to achieve your goal yourself, instead of carry you there.

Comment: @Zeta I have changed the code as asked.

Comment: +1: While this is better, it's still somewhat cryptic for most users, since you don't tell on which element you use `.prepend` and how you load the images. You can post an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ or other similar sites to provide an actual demo of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think jQuery wrap is what you are looking for.

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```
$(<image-selector>).wrap('<a href="<url>"></a>');
```